# In Shiny How to click on sidebar items and show panels related with each item with Shiny package

Tags: r, shiny

I need to create a sidebar with items, and each item should lead to its own panel.

I want to accomplish this using only the Shiny package, without relying on the shinydashboard package.

Currently, I have achieved this using JavaScript.

However, I would like to know if there is an alternative way to accomplish the same idea using only Shiny's package functions and avoiding JavaScript.

Bellow is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  style = 'display: flex;',

  div(
    class = "sidebar ",
    style = "
        background: #1C3D5A; padding: 1em; color: black;
     ",
    div(
      id = 'hamburger',
      style = 'display:flex; justify-content:end;',
      tags$img(src = 'img/hamburger_white.jpg',
               style = 'cursor: pointer;',
               width = '22px', height = '22px')
    ),
    div(
      id = 'menu_1',
      p('Menu 1', style = 'color:whitesmoke;text-align: center;'),
      style = 'cursor: pointer;',
      onclick = 'Shiny.setInputValue("selected_menu", 1)'
    ),
    div(
      id = 'menu_2',
      p('Menu 2', style = 'color:whitesmoke;text-align: center;'),
      style = 'cursor: pointer;',
      onclick = 'Shiny.setInputValue("selected_menu", 2)'
    ),
    div(
      id = 'menu_3',
      p('Menu 3', style = 'color:whitesmoke;text-align: center;'),
      style = 'cursor: pointer;',
      onclick = 'Shiny.setInputValue("selected_menu", 3)'
    ),
    div(
      id = 'menu_4',
      p('Menu 4', style = 'color:whitesmoke;text-align: center;'),
      style = 'cursor: pointer;',
      onclick = 'Shiny.setInputValue("selected_menu", 4)'
    )
  ),


  div(class = 'panels',
      style = 'height: 100vh;',
      uiOutput("panels")
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$panels <- renderUI({
    selected_menu <- input$selected_menu

    if (is.null(selected_menu)) {
      selected_menu <- 1  # Default menu item
    }

    if (selected_menu == 1) {
      div(id = 'panel1', style = 'margin-left: 20px;',
          h1('Panel 1'))
    } else if (selected_menu == 2) {
      div(id = 'panel2', style = 'margin-left: 20px;',
          h1('Panel 2'))
    } else if (selected_menu == 3) {
      div(id = 'panel3', style = 'margin-left: 20px;',
          h1('Panel 3'))
    } else if (selected_menu == 4) {
      div(id = 'panel4', style = 'margin-left: 20px;',
          h1('Panel 4'))
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

You would need any form of reactive input in your sidebar, `actionLink` for example. This encapsulates the `JavaScript` for you and you can react upon it in the server part (of course you can add some more css to style the look and feel of the `actionLinks`)

```r
library(shiny)
css <- HTML("
body > .container-fluid {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
   background: #1C3D5A;
   padding: 1em;
   color: black;
}

.sidebar > ul {
  color: whitesmoke;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar > ul >  li > a:any-link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: inherit;
}

.panels {
  height: 100vh;
}

.panel {
  margin-left: 20px
}
")


ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$head(
      singleton(
         tags$style(css)
      )
   ),
   div(
      class = "sidebar",
      tags$ul(
         lapply(1:4, \(i) tags$li(actionLink(paste0("lnk", i), paste("Menu", i))))
      )
   ),
   div(class = 'panels',
       uiOutput("panels")
   )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
   selected <- reactiveVal(1)
   
   obs <- lapply(1:4, \(i) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("lnk", i)]], selected(i))
   })
   
   
   output$panels <- renderUI({
      
      selected_menu <- selected()
      div(id = paste0("panel", selected_menu), class = "panel",
          h1(paste("Panel", selected_menu))
      )
   })
   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```